# Which list of VM available to AKS is correct?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-aks

I wanted to re-deploy AKS on a single machine on a new subscription. Several months ago, I have successfully set up `B1S` VM for this application, however, apparently it was not available today.

Now there are several conflicting sources of truth on what can and cannot be deployed as VM for AKS.

1. [List of VMs (pricing)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/linux/)
2. [List of VMs (previous gen)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/linux-previous/)
3. [AKS restricted VM sizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/quotas-skus-regions) - I assume that I can use whatever is not listed as unavailable.
4. [API documentation with available sizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managedclusters/createorupdate#containerservicevmsizetypes)
5. Error on cluster create (see below)

I evaluated availability of the following VMs of my interest in region `europe-west` in abovementioned five "sources of truth":

```
VM          | 1+2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 
-------------------------------
B1LS        |  +  |   |   | - |   
B1S         |  +  | - |   |   | <- this still works on existing cluster
B1MS        |  +  | - |   |   |
B2S         |  +  |   | + |   |
B2MS        |  +  |   | + |   |
A1 v2       |  +  | - | + |   |
A2 v2       |  +  |   | + |   |
Basic_A0    |  +  |   |   |   |
Basic_A1    |  +  |   |   |   |
Basic_A2    |  +  |   |   |   |
Standard_A0 |  +  | - |   |   |
Standard_A1 |  +  | - | + | - |
Standard_A2 |  +  |   | + | + |
```

(+) means is explicitly listed as available
(-) means is explicitly listed as not available or a failed deployment due to non-availability

Questions:

1. Where the truth lies on what is and is not available?
2. Can some unavailabilities result from temporary lack of machines?
3. Where can I find information that `B2S` is not available, apart from error on deployment?

*Error:*

`The available VM sizes are Standard_A2,Standard_A3,Standard_A4,Standard_A5,Standard_A6,Standard_A7,Standard_D15_v2,Standard_D16a_v4,Standard_D16as_v4,Standard_D2a_v4,Standard_D2as_v4,Standard_D32a_v4,Standard_D32as_v4,Standard_D48a_v4,Standard_D48as_v4,Standard_D4a_v4,Standard_D4as_v4,Standard_D64a_v4,Standard_D64as_v4,Standard_D8a_v4,Standard_D8as_v4,Standard_D96a_v4,Standard_D96as_v4,Standard_DS15_v2,Standard_E16a_v4,Standard_E16as_v4,Standard_E20a_v4,Standard_E20as_v4,Standard_E2a_v4,Standard_E2as_v4,Standard_E32a_v4,Standard_E32as_v4,Standard_E48a_v4,Standard_E48as_v4,Standard_E4a_v4,Standard_E4as_v4,Standard_E64a_v4,Standard_E64as_v4,Standard_E8a_v4,Standard_E8as_v4,Standard_E96a_v4,Standard_E96as_v4,Standard_F16s_v2,Standard_F2s_v2,Standard_F32s_v2,Standard_F48s_v2,Standard_F4s_v2,Standard_F64s_v2,Standard_F72s_v2,Standard_F8s_v2,Standard_G1,Standard_G2,Standard_G3,Standard_G4,Standard_G5,Standard_GS1,Standard_GS2,Standard_GS3,Standard_GS4,Standard_GS4-4,Standard_GS4-8,Standard_GS5,Standard_GS5-16,Standard_GS5-8,Standard_H16,Standard_H16m,Standard_H16mr,Standard_H16r,Standard_H8,Standard_H8m,Standard_L16s,Standard_L16s_v2,Standard_L32s,Standard_L32s_v2,Standard_L48s_v2,Standard_L4s,Standard_L64s_v2,Standard_L80s_v2,Standard_L8s,Standard_L8s_v2,Standard_M208ms_v2,Standard_M208s_v2,Standard_NC12_Promo,Standard_NC12s_v2,Standard_NC24_Promo,Standard_NC24r_Promo,Standard_NC24rs_v2,Standard_NC24s_v2,Standard_NC6_Promo,Standard_NC6s_v2,Standard_ND12s,Standard_ND24rs,Standard_ND24s,Standard_ND40rs_v2,Standard_ND6s,Standard_NV12_Promo,Standard_NV12s_v3,Standard_NV24_Promo,Standard_NV24s_v3,Standard_NV48s_v3 For more details, please visit https://aka.ms/cpu-quota"`

Comment: I think the size of Standard_B2s is available. Do you miss writing about it?

Comment: I am missing it even right now in europe-west, though available in us-east in azure portal. I sense this is related to temporary lack of Azure resources due to Covid...

Comment: I think it's region related. And maybe the restricted size is unavailable in all-region and each region is also a difference.

Answer (score 1):

The source of truth lies in AKS Engine.

https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/master/pkg/helpers/azure_skus.go

You have two set of list, one without and one with AcceleratedNetworking

https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/master/pkg/helpers/azure_skus_const.go

While there might be more ski that could be officially supported, this is the list that is used to enforce the SKU selection when creating an AKS cluster.

Comment: Standard_A1 deployment failed but is listed in your file, so this list at least must be somehow filtered on the go.

Comment: correct , AKS could be adding extra check on top of this list.

Comment: the restricted list from AKS is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/quotas-skus-regions#restricted-vm-sizes